# Why Goku doesnt use the Super Saiyan Blue kaioken anymore?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In Dragon Ball Super, when fighting Hit, Goku used the super saiyan blue kaioken or also called super saiyajin god super saiyajin kaioken. With this technique, he could get even 10 times stronger. But now he's inferior to Black, and he has been defeated 2 times by him, but he doesnt use it as a last resource. Why is that?

Comment: probably because it was filler/non Canon in the Manga, but who knows. Goku Beat hit by utilizing SSG form, then just before the Time stop, switched to SSGSS, throwing Hit off enough for a decisive victory, though he ofcourse gave up after that like in the anime.

Comment: well now he just used it again

Comment: Ya, in Anime Canon he can use it, though of course it still has its potential costs. The anime is becoming torn between following what the Manga will do, and its own thing, and its causing some pretty big inconsistencies.

Comment: @Ryan To be fair, for _Super_, either the manga is following the anime, or they're both being produced simultaneously (with neither one following the other); I can't remember which.  The anime doesn't actually have filler, because of this, because it doesn't need to give the manga time to get further ahead.  If I remember correctly, Toriyama comes up with the storylines for both, then their creators work from there (explaining the differences between the two).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a ton of disadvantages using Super Saiyan Blue Kaio-ken:

- It has only a 10% chance of working and a 90% of failing, which had a chance of killing him.
- Goku is only able to maintain Super Saiyan Blue Kaio-ken x10 for short periods of time because it puts a great deal of strain on his body. While Potara fusion could last for an hour.
- Goku began to suffer severe muscle convulsions as he powered back down to base form and developed [Delayed Onset Ki Disorder](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Delayed_Onset_Ki_Disorder) which includes significant decrease in ki control and capacity.
- King Kai warned Goku to not use this form as the user might incapable of getting stronger.

Though, Goku did used Super Saiyan Blue Kaio-ken once to escape Fusion Zamasu's grasp and send him flying with a swift kick. Goku manages to destroy Fusion Zamasu's Ring of Light, but quickly returns to base form, unable to move. See [here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Blue_Kaio-ken#Overview) for more details.